# Unity-How to make recursive function return correct value that only if condition is true

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

what I want to achieve is convert the relationship between current selected object and it's specific parent to path pattern in hierarchy window.For example, from the screenshot, the Test_01 and Test_02 is the specific parent, and if the current selected obj is ABBB under Test_01, then I will have a path like Test_01/AB/ABB/ABBB, my code is below, my problem is because the function *findPathInScence* is recursive, the variable *pt* seems only can get the first value it return, like the pt always empty but scenePath always what I want. How to make the function return  the value only when if is true? please help.[image: structure in hierarchy] [image: result]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class Test
{
    string tempPath;
    private string findPathInScence(GameObject gs)
    {

        string scenePath = "";
        if (gs.name.Contains("Test"))
        {
            scenePath = gs.name + tempPath;
            Debug.Log("scenePath:  " + scenePath);
            tempPath = "";

        }
        else
        {
            tempPath = "/" + gs.name + tempPath;
            findPathInScence(gs.transform.parent.gameObject);
        }
        return scenePath;
    }

    [MenuItem("GameObject/printPath", false, 20)]
    static void printPathInScene()
    {
        Test t = new Test();
        string pt = t.findPathInScence(Selection.activeGameObject);
        Debug.Log("pt:    " + pt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue

In the case that your object does **not match** `Test` you set

```
scenePath = "";
```

and then regardless of the result of the recursive `findPathInScence` you simply return

```
return scenePath;
```

unlike the `tempPath` which is a field the `scenePath` is a local variable only existent during the individual run of the method.

The last recursive call for the object `Test_01` actually returns the correct path, **however** you do not use it anywhere!

=> **For any selected object that has not `Test` the return value is always empty!**

---

#### Solution with recursion

**If** you really want to go recursive you have to properly get the path of the recursive run correctly. You could do it like e.g.

```
public static class TransformExtensions
{
    public static string GetScenePath(this Transform transform, string stopIfContains, StringBuilder path = null)
    {
        if (path == null)
        {
            path = new StringBuilder();
        }

        if (gs.name.Contains(stopIfContains))
        {
            var scenePath = path.Insert(0, transform.name);
            Debug.Log($"{nameof(scenePath)}: {scenePath}");
            return scenePath.ToString();
        }

        path.Insert(0, gs.name).Insert(0, '/');
        return GetScenePath(transform.parent, path);
    }
}
```

and

```
Debug.Log("pt:    " + Selection.activeGameObject.transform.GetScenePath("Test"));
```

---

#### Solution without recursion

But why even use recursion?

You can simply bubble up in a loop which is way easier to understand, maintain and debug.

like e.g. ([source](https://answers.unity.com/questions/8500/how-can-i-get-the-full-path-to-a-gameobject.html))

```
public static class TransformExtensions
{
    public static string GetScenePath(this Transform transform)
    {
         string path = transform.name;

         while (transform.parent != null)
         {
             transform = transform.parent;
             path = transform.name + "/" + path;
         }

         return path;
     }
}
```

or maybe without so many `string` concatenations

```
public static class TransformExtensions
{
    public static string GetScenePath(this Transform transform)
    {
         var sb = new StringBuilder(transform.name);

         while (transform.parent != null)
         {
             transform = transform.parent;
             sb.Insert(0, '/').Insert(0, transform.name);
         }

         return sb.ToString();
     }
}
```

now you can simply call

```
Debug.Log("pt:    " + Selection.activeGameObject.transform.GetScenePath());
```

---

Or with your additional exit strategy (name match)

```
public static class TransformExtensions
{
    public static string GetScenePath(this Transform transform, string stopIfContains)
    {
         var sb = new StringBuilder(transform.name);

         while (transform.parent != null && !transform.name.Contains(stopIfContains))
         {
             transform = transform.parent;
             sb.Insert(0, '/').Insert(0, transform.name);
         }

         return sb.ToString();
     }
}
```

and

```
Debug.Log("pt:    " + Selection.activeGameObject.transform.GetScenePath("Test"));
```